# Search through JSON to find correct 'set', then output value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I'm currenty trying to extract information from a website's API JSON output.
Here is what I have, and it almost works perfectly:

```
def get_player_stats
  uri = URI("http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getPlayerStats?accountId=#{CGI.escape(@summoner.acctId)}&season=CURRENT&key=KEYID")
  resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  hash = JSON(resp.body)

  solo_ranked_elo = hash['playerStatSummaries']['playerStatSummarySet'][2]['maxRating']
  puts solo_ranked_elo

end
```

The problem is that the  `['playerStatSummarySet'][1]` values will change depending on the player. So for one player their `maxRating` would be in set `[1]`, but another player's `maxRating` will be in set `[6]`.

I need to search for the set where the `RankedSolo5x5` value exists then I can go about outputting the `maxRating`. How would I go about this?

Here are two example files I'm using for comparison:

http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getPlayerStats?accountId=22031699&season=CURRENT&key=KEYID

http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getPlayerStats?accountId=23529170&season=CURRENT&key=KEYID

I hope that is clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full example

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI("http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getPlayerStats?accountId=#{ARGV[0]}&season=CURRENT&key=KEYID")
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
stat_summary = JSON(resp.body)['playerStatSummaries']['playerStatSummarySet']

stat_summary.each_with_index do |obj, i| # it's this loop that answers your question
  next if obj['playerStatSummaryType'] != 'RankedSolo5x5'

  puts obj['maxRating']
  break
end
```

`ARGV[0]` is a command line argument value for the `accountID`. You'd save the above to some `max_rating` file, `chmod +x max_rating` and then run

```
./max_rating 22031699       # Outputs 1421
./max_rating 23529170       # Outputs 1237
```

Comment: The accountId I already have saved to the database through another method, that's why I have `#{CGI.escape(@summoner.acctId)}` (not sure if the CGI.escape the correct usage though). Don't I need to search for RankedSolo5x5, to get RankedSolo5x5's maxRating? As there are other maxRating's for RankedTeam5x5, RankedTeam3x3, etc. I'm not sure what you mean by saving it to another file? I'm using this in a Rails app. Thanks alot Deefour, it's really appreciated!

Comment: I've updated my answer to search for `playerStatSummaryType` having a value `'RankedSolo5x5`. I don't have your rails application; that is why I have written my answer as a standalone CLI script. I'm not suggesting you use `ARGV[0]` in your rails app; that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much! And sorry for my ignorance :)